# Is it possible to access the key value pair without using iterator in map?

Tags: c++, c++11, matrix

I am currently using std::map to store sparse matrix:

```
std::map<std::pair<int, int>, double> matrix;
```

To insert I do

```
matrix[std::make_pair(i,j)] = value;
```

After I have created the matrix I want to do (matrix-transpose * matrix) for this I have to do (00*00) + (10*10) + (20*20)  (accessing vertical column )... Since iterator goes from (00) (01) (02) (access horizontal column)... I can't use std iterator.

To achieve (00)*(00) + (10*10) + .. I use while loop that use x1, y1 and x2, y2 to access the matrix elements.

So now My question is (also if what I am doing makes sense) how can I access the first and second pair of the std::pair without using iterator?

Comment: Can you write a custom comparator that will store the elements in the map in the order you would want to traverse them?

Comment: You access the first and the second value of a `std::pair` by accessing the `first` and `second` class members. *shrug*. Your question is unclear.

Comment: Transpose iteration of this structure is indeed inefficient.  There's really no choice other than looking up each index pair at a time to see if the element exists. That's why many sparse matrix frameworks store a list per column.  But your question doesn't seem to follow from your description.  Since you can't iterate the whole thing, you have to look up the elements you want.  What does that have to do with accessing values of the pair???

Comment: The cost of doing `matrix.find(std::make_pair(x,x))` should be relatively cheap.

Comment: Hard to imagine a less suitable implementation for sparse matrix.

Comment: Just a note: you're really going to want to stick with one of the well known sparse storage formats if you want your implementation to be remotely quick. A std::map implementation is not only slow to iterate through but really cache unfriendly. Take a look here: http://netlib.org/linalg/html_templates/node90.html

Answer (score 2):

An "easy" way to approach this is to write `transpose`:

```
std::map<std::pair<int, int>, double> transpose(
  std::map<std::pair<int, int>, double> const& in
) {
  std::map<std::pair<int, int>, double> r;
  for (auto&& e:in)
    r[std::make_pair( e.first.second, e.first.first )] = e.second;
  return r;
}
```

but this requires allocating a brand new matrix.

Another approach is to have a matrix-view.  A matrix-view is a:

```
template<class R> using matrix_func = std::function< R( std::pair<int,int> ) >;
template<class R>
struct matrix_view_base:matrix_func<R> {
  std::pair<int, int> dimensions;
  matrix_view( matrix_func<R> f, std::pair<int, int> d ):
    matrix_func<R>(std::move(f)),
    dimensions(d)
  {}
};
using matrix_view = matrix_view_base<double&>;
using matrix_const_view = matrix_view_base<double>;
```

a function that maps coordinates to doubles with knowledge of max size.

We then write an inteverter:

```
matrix_view invert( matrix_view in ) {
  return {
    [in]( std::pair<int, int> index )->double& {
      return in(index.second, index.first);
    },
    in.dimensions
  };
}
matrix_const_view invert( matrix_const_view in ) {
  return {
    [in]( std::pair<int, int> index )->double {
      return in(index.second, index.first);
    },
    in.dimensions
  };
}
```

with some functions to generate said views:

```
matrix_view view_of( matrix& m ) {
  return {
    [&](std::pair<int, int> idx)->double& {
      return m[idx];
    },
    // calculate dimensions
  };
}
matrix_const_view view_of( matrix const& m ) {
  return {
    [&](std::pair<int, int> idx)->double {
      auto it = m.find(idx);
      if (it == m.end()) return 0.0;
      return *it;
    },
    // calculate dimensions
  };
}
matrix_const_view const_view_of( matrix const& m ) {
  return view_of(m);
}
```

Now you just have to write multiply for matrix views:

```
matrix_const_view multiply( matrix_const_view lhs, matrix_const_view rhs ) {
  return {
    [=](std::pair<int,int> idx)->double{
      // calculate value at idx using lhs(...) and rhs(...) return values
    },
    // calculate dimensions
  };
}
```

Now this isn't perfect, because perfectly you'd be able to determine where the `0`s are faster than doing two lookups.  But the idea is that you create a view class that represents a view into a matrix, do operations on those, and only solidify into an actual matrix when you need to store the result.

This permits transpose to be cheap.